# Could not find any remote repositories associated with MY GOOGLE APP ENGINE APPLICATION

Tags: wordpress, git, google-app-engine, repository, gcloud

When I deploy my WordPress application to Google App Engine using by:

```
gcloud ... --verbosity=info ...
```

I have the following script said:

> Beginning deployment of service [default]...
> ...
> INFO: Could not find any remote repositories associated with [../coding/GCP/domain.com/2017-01-03-test]. Cloud diagnostic tools may not be able to display the correct source code for this deployment.
>   ...
>   Updating service [default]...done.

Anyone knows how to solve the INFO?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I never used the Google Repositories. When I just uploaded my wordpress application to App Engine with 2nd generation, I got the INFO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/) are Google-hosted private git repositories where code for applications that run in the Google cloud can be stored.

This allows close integration with Google's debugging and diagnostic tools, which is useful but not essential.

The message

> INFO: Could not find any remote repositories associated with [../coding/GCP/domain.com/2017-01-03-test]. Cloud diagnostic tools may not be able to display the correct source code for this deployment.

is *advisory*, explaining that this integration is not available because the application's source code is not hosted in the Google repos.